# Firmware bug | tpm_crb msft0101 firmware bug after updating to the kernel 5.1.6

Tags: boot, kernel, kubuntu, 19.04

I updated Kubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04 recently. There was no firmware bug with kernel version 5.0.0 (the one came with the Kubuntu distro). I updated the kernel from version 5.0.0 to 5.1.6. When the computer boots, the following black boot screen appears, stays there for a while, and then starts.

```
[    1.231218] tpm_crb MSFT0101: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire
[    1.231475] tpm_crb MSFT0101: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire
[    1.296345] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

To be more specific, when I executed the following command `dmesg | grep tpm_crb`, the following results appeared.

```
[    1.218801] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
[    1.218853] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
```

My laptop is Asus s15 x510UA, with Intel graphics.

Comment: If you don't need TPM, just disable it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, Thank you for the response. I was looking online about disabling TPM. How can I do that? I also checked BIOS menu and nothing is there.

Comment: It's UEFI actually, it replaced BIOS along time ago. But either BIOS or UEFI must have settings fir TPM, if the chip is there.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, thank you again. My laptop has a dual boot. I logged in Windows, and I checked the device manager. I saw that TPM 2.0 is there as a security device, and tried to remove/uninstall it. It didn't go. I was looking in the bios/UEFI, but surprisingly nothing related to TPM is there.

Comment: If you have Windows then that's a reason to keep TPM enabled as it may be needed for some features. Also there's absolutely no point in removing/uninstalling it from within Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Same here but with newer Kernels. As I use an Asus Laptop too, which doesn´t allow deactivating tpm (see other forums), it took me hours to figure out what was wrong. I simply used Linux Mint with the Linux 5.15.0-60-generic Kernel instead of 5.16 and everything was perfectly fine. Deactivating tpm is no option. You probably will have to use an older Kernel. Because Asus is like: YoUr ArE noT SUpPosEd tO rUn LInuX

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1288915)